# Web Apps Azure High Traffic

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure Web Apps to host my website. The website is loaded from a native apps for iOS and Android. During normal days non peak time , the web is operating as expected. However, from time to time , we are going to push out notification via apns or google gcm and that will drive users back to the apps. From there, content will be loaded from the website which is hosted from the Azure Web Apps.

During this peak times where there are thousands of requests coming in, there will be very high degree of fallout which results in errors.

It is shown in the picture below . 
[Traffic of the web apps after the push notification blasts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKvIH.png)

I have make sure that the database will not have any bottleneck during the operation. We are using SQL from Azure as well.

From the new portal, we are using service tier 'S1' for the App Services. 
Previously, when the apps are developed, Web Apps and Mobile Services are separate service which are now join to become App Services.

Is there anything I could adjust from the azure backend or there is something which I missed out to handle ? Currently , we are also making the instance to be auto scaling.

As in conclusion, during high concurrent requests rushing in, the web apps seems to stop responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to implement the retry logic if there is no such yet and troubleshoot using the different modes.

UPD:
There is a detailed "analyzing performance" official guidance here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation/ .

The most simple way to understand (or just mitigate) if the issue if somehow related to the underlying backend (throttling etc) is to change the mode site is working in. In your case, it can be S or even P.

Next step, if we eliminate the possibility of the throttling/etc, is to implement the diagnostics. My favourite tool is Application Insights, there is New Relic and other great tools as well. There are good guidances i saw and used:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/monitoring-and-telemetry

https://github.com/mspnp/performance-optimization/blob/master/Assessing-System-Performance-Against-KPI.md#insertlink#

So, there is not silver answer about your question - highload is highload :-) Without access to the sources and website, and load tests results it is difficult to say what component of the project behaves itself bad.

---

If that is the helpful answer, please mark it as a helpful or as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: the powerful mode means adjusting to a higher tier for the app services ?